# I dont know where the dimmer needs to go

Tags: lighting, kitchens

Have seen comments that say the dimmer in a 4-way configuration must be at one of the ends of the circuit.  Already have a dimmer that functions well, but its mechanically failing.  Since it works can I assume that its at one of the ends?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box the dimmer is in, with the power off at the breaker and the dimmer turned off but not disconnected?

Comment: I don't see how it couldn't *not* be. @ThreePhaseEel - what would all that tell you?

Comment: @Mazura it'd let me confirm that nothing weird is going on